# Remove Edge From React Google Maps?

Tags: reactjs

I need to remove the edges from react google maps when its drawing boundary.

```
<GoogleMap onClick={(value)=>{
      props.map_data.getClassName(value)
      }} defaultZoom={9} defaultCenter={props.locationCoords} defaultOptions={{ gestureHandling: "greedy" }}>
      <Polygon
        paths={props.reversedCoords}
        // geodesic={true}
        options={{
          fillColor: `#ff0000`,
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          strokeColor: '#47a4fa',
          strokeOpacity: 0.7,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          clickable: true,
          editable: true,
          zIndex: -1,
          geodesic:false          
        }}
/>
</GoogleMap>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG6fL.png)

Comment: Do you want to remove the marks (white dot marker)?

Comment: I need to remove the mute dots in between white dots

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the mute dots in between white dots but in alternative way you can update the state variable to edit polygon.

Check below code

```
<GoogleMap onClick={(value) => {
  this.setState({ polygonEditable: false });
  props.map_data.getClassName(value)
}} defaultZoom={9} defaultCenter={props.locationCoords} defaultOptions={{ gestureHandling: "greedy" }}>
  <Polygon
    paths={props.reversedCoords}
    onClick={e => this.setState({ polygonEditable: true })}
    // geodesic={true}
    options={{
      fillColor: `#ff0000`,
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      strokeColor: '#47a4fa',
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      clickable: true,
      editable: this.state.polygonEditable,
      zIndex: -1,
      geodesic: false
    }}
  />
</GoogleMap>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Hi Clue Mediator,
Thanks for your response, i need to remove the mute dots in react google maps

Comment: You can't remove the mute dots in between white dots. So I have provided alternative solution for it. Can you check above code I think this will work for you.

Comment: Hi Clue Mediator, 
Thanks for your response
The above code is working fine, But its shows mute dots on Click event .There is any other solution to solve this issue .

Comment: Yes that's the behaviour of the google map. You can edit the Polygon via those dots. So I don't think so do you have any other choice to hide it.

Comment: @RameshSankar If it's useful then can you please mark an answer as accepted and Vote up? So it will helpful to other developers as well.

Comment: As per your request, Your answer didn't solve my purpose as this is an integral part of my project, If you could share this question it will be helpful for me to further go on with the project and if you could find any other alternative it would be even more helpful. Thanks !!! @Clue Mediator